# Redirect invalid subdomain request to proper location

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, subdomain, wordpress, wildcard-subdomain

We've got site at a subdomain (new.example.com) and previous version of the site at the root (example.com). The previous version is a WordPress network with wildcard subdomains. The static subdomain was created in Plesk 10 and works fine (we've got a zzz-wildcard.conf file with the verified correct settings).

Our problem right now, and it's a silly one, is that some site users are attempting to access the subdomain through www.new.example.com, which rather than redirecting to new.example.com, is intercepted by example.com.

How should we setup our server to intercept this request and route it to the correct location?

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you use a "sub-wildcard-subdomain"?

```
*.new.example.com CNAME new.example.com
```

That should do the trick

Comment: Hmm...will give that a try. We've added `www.new.example.com CNAME new.exmaple.com` with no luck

Comment: Nope, that definitely didn't work. The WordPress multisite still intercepts the request.

Comment: So why not a ServerAlias or a Redirect Permant